# Two strings in static equilibrium. Why not use the pythagorean theorem to combine vectors?

Tags: vectors, equilibrium

I have been working through a physics course and came across the problem: two strings holding a weight in static equilibrium. It all made sense, except for this: Why don't you use pythagorean theorem to combine the X and Y tension vectors?
If you look at this video which explains how to do the problem you will see that when he is done, he appears to have the X component of the tension which he presents as the answer:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxM9lsbUbpw
I know there is a reason behind this, so I came here to see what it was.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "use arctan to combine the vectors"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the 'pythagorean theorem'. I fixed the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - in the video, the instructor calculates $A$ and $B$ which are the total tension in the cables. Taking a screen shot at 6:16 shows this:

[image]

The horizontal components are $A \cos 60$ and $B\cos 40$ respectively - and these cancel exactly. $A$ and $B$ are indeed the total tension. You *could* get that by summing the $x$ and $y$ components according to Pythagoras' theorem - you would get $A = \sqrt{A^2 \cos^2 60 + A^2 \sin^2 60}$. Of course you can see that since $\cos^2 60 + \sin^2 60 = 1$, this gets you the same result...